# IKVMC, MONO: ClassCastException while deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, xamarin, ikvm

We are using Xamarin+IKVM to compile our java code for iOS platform.  I am getting ClassCastException when deserializing the data serialized earlier to a file:

> ```
> .lang.ClassCastException
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1943)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1850)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:361)
>   at com.kiwi.animaltown.UserAssetRenderer.deSerialize(UserAssetRenderer.java:2072)
> ```

Here is the class I am trying to serialize:

```
  public class TestSerializeClass  implements Serializable
    {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1218312212872650919L;
        public int leftNonTransparentX = -1;
        public TestSerializeClass()
        {
        }
    }
```

For serialization:

```
obOut = new ObjectOutputStream(bufferOutStream);
                for(int x = 10; x < 20; x = x+1) {
                    TestSerializeClass obj = new TestSerializeClass();
                    obOut.writeObject(obj);
                }
```

For deserialization:

```
        inStr = AssetConfig.assetStorage.getFileHandle(fileName).read();
        BufferedInputStream buffStr = new BufferedInputStream(inStr, 8*1024);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(buffStr);

        try {
             Object obj;
             while (true) {
                obj = (TestSerializeClass)in.readObject();
             }
          catch...
```

Comment: What is `in` in `in.readObject()` from desrialization code?

Comment: Edited the code. Now it should be clear

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm late to the party, and frankly I haven't touched IKVM for almost a decade now, but I do recall having classloading issues during serialization at the time.

Instead of digging in, what we did to sidestep the issue was rely on a third party serialization library. We ended up being happy with XStream. Nowadays, I would suggest using a portable serialization solution (e.g. something that works on top of JSON or MessagePack). This way you have more degrees of freedom if something doesn't work out—you can just swap out the serialization subsystem into a platform specific implementation.